# Comparing video recording algorithms in Java: no-compression vs. naive diff compressor

Tags: java, compression, canvas, javafx, video

Usage of the program is in [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/100006286710078/videos/967672304471719/).

**Intro**

In this JavaFX program, a user is presented with a white canvas with a black circle at the center of the canvas. Then, the user has 10 seconds to record a video by dragging the circle via mouse. During the recording, there are two different video recording algorithms recording each frame. The algorithms are as follows:

1. No-compression: each frame is recorded on a pixel-by-pixel basis; one bit per pixel (white vs. black),
2. Naive compressor: the first frame is stored just like in 1, yet after that it records only the "diff" between two consecutive frames.

More precisely, in algorithm 2, each new frame is computed as follows: Compare the previous and the next frames; store the number of pixels \$N\$ that has changed between the two. Next, for each changed pixel \$(x, y)\$, store it after written value of \$N\$.

**Critique request**

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

**Source code**

**`com.github.coderodde.compression.util.BitArrayBuilder.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.compression.util;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * This class implements a bit array builder for storing the video frames.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jul 18, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Jul 18, 2023)
 */
public final class BitArrayBuilder {

    private static final int DEFAULT_LONG_ARRAY_CAPACITY = 50_000;
    
    /**
     * This array stores the actual bits.
     */
    private long[] bitArray;
    
    /**
     * This field specifies how many bits there are in this builder.
     */
    private int size;
    
    /**
     * Constructs a bit array builder with default capacity.
     */
    public BitArrayBuilder() {
        this(DEFAULT_LONG_ARRAY_CAPACITY * Long.SIZE);
    }
    
    /**
     * Constructs a bit array builder capable of holding 
     * {@code initialNumberOfBits} bits.
     * 
     * @param initialNumberOfBits the initial requested capacity.
     */
    public BitArrayBuilder(int initialNumberOfBits) {
        this.bitArray = new long[getInitialNumberOfLongs(initialNumberOfBits)];
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the number of bits stored in this builder.
     * 
     * @return the number of bits.
     */
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
    
    /**
     * Appends {@code length} least-significant bits from {@code bitsToAppend} 
     * to this bit array builder.
     * 
     * @param bitsToAppend the {@code long} value holding the bits.
     * @param length       the number of least-significant bits to append.
     */
    public void appendBits(long bitsToAppend, int length) {
        expandTableIfNeeded(size + length);
        
        for (int bitIndex = 0; bitIndex < length; bitIndex++) {
            appendBit(((bitsToAppend >> bitIndex) & 0x1L) != 0);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Reads {@code length} bits starting from index {@code index}.
     * 
     * @param index  the leftmost index of the bit range to read.
     * @param length the length of the bit range to read.
     * @return the {@code length} bits.
     */
    public long readBits(int index, int length) {
        long ret = 0L;
        
        for (int i = index, bitIndex = 0; i < index + length; i++, bitIndex++) {
            boolean bit = readBit(i);
            
            if (bit) {
                ret |= (1 << bitIndex);
            }
        }
        
        return ret;
    }
    
    /**
     * Reads the {@code index}th bit.
     * 
     * @param index the index of the bit to read.
     * @return a bit, {@code true} for the 1 and {@code false} for the 0.
     */
    private boolean readBit(int index) {
        int longIndex = index / Long.SIZE;
        long dataLong = bitArray[longIndex];
        index %= Long.SIZE;
        long mask = 1L << index;
        return (dataLong & mask) != 0;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the shortest byte array capable of holding all the bits in this
     * bit array builder.
     * 
     * @return the byte content of this builder.
     */
    public byte[] getBytes() {
        int numberOfBytes = size / Byte.SIZE;
        int remainder = size % Byte.SIZE;
        int byteArrayLength = numberOfBytes + (remainder != 0 ? 1 : 0);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[byteArrayLength];
        
        for (int byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < bytes.length; byteIndex++) {
            bytes[byteIndex] = getDataByte(byteIndex);
        }
        
        return bytes;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the {@code byteIndex}th byte.
     * 
     * @param byteIndex the byte index.
     * @return the byte value at index {@code byteIndex}.
     */
    private byte getDataByte(int byteIndex) {
        long longData = bitArray[byteIndex / Long.BYTES];
        byteIndex %= Long.BYTES;
        
        switch (byteIndex) {
            case 0:
                return (byte)(longData);
                
            case 1:
                return (byte)((longData >> 8) & 0xFF);
                
            case 2:
                return (byte)((longData >> 16) & 0xFF);
                
            case 3:
                return (byte)((longData >> 24) & 0xFF);
                
            case 4:
                return (byte)((longData >> 32) & 0xFF);
                
            case 5:
                return (byte)((longData >> 40) & 0xFF);
                
            case 6:
                return (byte)((longData >> 48) & 0xFF);
                
            case 7:
                return (byte)((longData >> 56) & 0xFF);
                
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Should not get here ever.");
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Implements the actual appending of a bit to the tail of this bit array
     * builder.
     * 
     * @param bit the bit to append. If is {@code true}, a 1-bit is appended,
     *            and 0-bit otherwise.
     */
    private void appendBit(boolean bit) {
        int longIndex = size / Long.SIZE;
        int longBitsIndex = size - longIndex * Long.SIZE;
        long mask = 0x1L << longBitsIndex;
        
        if (bit) {
            bitArray[longIndex] |= mask;
        } else {
            bitArray[longIndex] &= ~mask;
        }
        
        size++;
    }
    
    /**
     * Computes the initial number of {@code long} values sufficient to hold 
     * {@code initialNumberOfBits} bits.
     * 
     * @param initialNumberOfBits the number of bits to accommodate.
     * @return the number of longs needed to store all the bits.
     */
    private int getInitialNumberOfLongs(int initialNumberOfBits) {
        int longs = initialNumberOfBits / Long.SIZE;
        int remainder = initialNumberOfBits % Long.SIZE;
        return longs + (remainder != 0 ? 1 : 0);
    }
    
    /**
     * Doubles the capacity of the actual bit array.
     * 
     * @param requestedCapacity the requested capacity.
     */
    private void expandTableIfNeeded(int requestedCapacity) {
        if (requestedCapacity > bitArray.length * Long.SIZE) {
            long[] newBitArray = 
                    Arrays.copyOf(
                            bitArray, 
                            Math.max(bitArray.length * 2, requestedCapacity));
            
            int sizeToCopy = size / Long.SIZE + (size % Long.SIZE == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            System.arraycopy(bitArray, 0, newBitArray, 0, sizeToCopy);
            bitArray = newBitArray;
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.compression.util.CircleVideoShape.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.compression.util;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * This class implements the circle video shape for recording.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jul 18, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Jul 18, 2023)
 */
public final class CircleVideoShape {
    
    /**
     * The width of the canvas that contains this circle.
     */
    private final int pixelMatrixWidth;
    
    /**
     * The height of the canvas that contains this circle.
     */
    private final int pixelMatrixHeight;
    
    /**
     * The radius of this circle.
     */
    private final int radius;
    
    /**
     * The center X-coordinate.
     */
    private final AtomicInteger centerX;
    
    /**
     * The center Y-coordinate.
     */
    private final AtomicInteger centerY;
    
    /**
     * Constructs a new circle.
     * 
     * @param pixelMatrixWidth  the width of the containing canvas.
     * @param pixelMatrixHeight the height of the containing canvas.
     * @param radius            the radius of the circle.
     */
    public CircleVideoShape(
            int pixelMatrixWidth,
            int pixelMatrixHeight,
            int radius) {
        this.pixelMatrixWidth = pixelMatrixWidth;
        this.pixelMatrixHeight = pixelMatrixHeight;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.centerX = new AtomicInteger(pixelMatrixWidth / 2);
        this.centerY = new AtomicInteger(pixelMatrixHeight / 2);
    }
    
    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
    
    public int getCenterX() {
        return centerX.get();
    }
    
    public int getCenterY() {
        return centerY.get();
    }
    
    public void setCenterX(int centerX) {
        this.centerX.set(centerX);
    }
    
    public void setCenterY(int centerY) {
        this.centerY.set(centerY);
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the entire pixel color matrix.
     * 
     * @return pixel color matrix.
     */
    public PixelColor[][] getColorMatrix() {
        PixelColor[][] pixelColorMatrix = new PixelColor[pixelMatrixHeight]
                                                        [pixelMatrixWidth];
        
        for (int y = 0; y < pixelMatrixHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < pixelMatrixWidth; x++) {
                pixelColorMatrix[y][x] = getPixelColorAt(x, y);
            }
        }
        
        return pixelColorMatrix;
    }
    
    /**
     * Computes the pixel color of the pixel at coordinates {@code (x, y)]}.
     * 
     * @param x the X-coordinate of the pixel.
     * @param y the Y-coordinate of the pixel.
     * @return the actual color of the pixel.
     */
    private PixelColor getPixelColorAt(int x, int y) {
        int dx = x - centerX.get();
        int dy = y - centerY.get();
        int dist2 = dx * dx + dy * dy;
        double dist = Math.sqrt(dist2);
        return dist > radius ? PixelColor.WHITE : PixelColor.BLACK;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.compression.util.PixelColor.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.compression.util;

public enum PixelColor {
    WHITE,
    BLACK;
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.compression.util.Utils.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.compression.util;

/**
 * This class contains various utility methods.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jul 18, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Jul 18, 2023)
 */
public final class Utils {
    
    public static void sleep(long milliseconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            
        }
    }
    
    public static void sleep(long milliseconds, int nanoseconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milliseconds, nanoseconds);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            
        }
    }
    
    public static void sleep(SleepDuration sleepDuration) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepDuration.millisecondsPart, 
                         sleepDuration.nanosecondsPart);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the minimum number of bits sufficient to store the value
     * {@code maximumValue}.
     * 
     * @param maximumValue the integer value we wish to store.
     * @return number of bits sufficient to store the input value.
     */
    public static int computeNumberOfBitsToStore(int maximumValue) {
        if (maximumValue == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
            
        int bits = 0;
        
        while (maximumValue != 0) {
            maximumValue /= 2;
            bits++;
        }
        
        return bits;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the number of nanoseconds which it takes to call the 
     * {@link Trhead.sleep}.
     * 
     * @return the number of nanoseconds. 
     */
    public static long getThreadSleepCallDuration() {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        sleep(0L);
        long duration = System.nanoTime() - start;
        return Math.max(duration, 0L);
    }
    
    public static SleepDuration getFrameSleepDuration(int framesPerSecond) {
        long sleepCallDuration = getThreadSleepCallDuration();
        long durationNanoseconds = 1_000_000_000 / framesPerSecond 
                                                 - sleepCallDuration;
        
        long durationMilliseconds = durationNanoseconds / 1_000_000;
        long durationNanosecondsPart = 
                durationNanoseconds - durationMilliseconds * 1_000_000;
        
        return new SleepDuration(durationMilliseconds, 
                                 (int) durationNanosecondsPart);
    }
    
    public static final class SleepDuration {
        public final long millisecondsPart;
        public final int nanosecondsPart;
        
        SleepDuration(long milliseconds, int nanoseconds) {
            this.millisecondsPart = milliseconds;
            this.nanosecondsPart = nanoseconds;
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.compression.util.VideoScreenCanvas.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.compression.util;

import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

/**
 * This class implements the video screen canvas.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jul 18, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Jul 18, 2023)
 */
public final class VideoScreenCanvas extends Canvas {

    public static final int VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_WIDTH = 1200;
    public static final int VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_HEIGHT = 800;
    private static final int CIRCLE_VIDEO_SHAPE_RADIUS = 100;
    
    private final GraphicsContext graphicsContext;
    private final CircleVideoShape circleVideoShape = 
            new CircleVideoShape(
                    VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_WIDTH, 
                    VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_HEIGHT,
                    CIRCLE_VIDEO_SHAPE_RADIUS);
    
    private final int matrixWidth;
    private final int matrixHeight;
    
    public VideoScreenCanvas() {
        super(VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_WIDTH, VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        
        this.matrixWidth = VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_WIDTH;
        this.matrixHeight = VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_HEIGHT;
        this.graphicsContext = getGraphicsContext2D();
        
        clear();
        paintCircleVideoShape();
    }
    
    public void clear() {
        graphicsContext.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        graphicsContext.fillRect(0, 0, matrixWidth, matrixHeight);
    }
    
    public void paintCircleVideoShape() {
        graphicsContext.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        graphicsContext.fillOval(
                circleVideoShape.getCenterX() - circleVideoShape.getRadius(),
                circleVideoShape.getCenterY() - circleVideoShape.getRadius(),
                circleVideoShape.getRadius() * 2,
                circleVideoShape.getRadius() * 2);
    }
    
    public void drawFrame(Image image) {
        graphicsContext.drawImage(image, 0.0, 0.0);
    }
    
    public Image convertFramePixelsToImage(Color[][] framePixels) {
        WritableImage raster = 
                new WritableImage(
                        framePixels[0].length, 
                        framePixels.length);
        
        PixelWriter pixelWriter = raster.getPixelWriter();
        
        for (int y = 0; y < framePixels.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < framePixels[0].length; x++) {
                pixelWriter.setColor(x, y, framePixels[y][x]);
            }
        }
        
        return raster;
    }
    
    public CircleVideoShape getCircleVideoShape() {
        return circleVideoShape;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.compression.video.app.VideoCompressionApp.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.compression.video.app;

import com.github.coderodde.compression.util.VideoScreenCanvas;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class VideoCompressionApp extends Application {
    
    static final int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 25;
    static final int VIDEO_DURATION_SECONDS = 10;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("VideoCompressionApp 1.6 - by coderodde");
        showBeginRecordingHint();
        
        VideoScreenCanvas videoScreenCanvas = new VideoScreenCanvas();
        videoScreenCanvas.paintCircleVideoShape();
        
        EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                int x = (int) mouseEvent.getX();
                int y = (int) mouseEvent.getY();
                videoScreenCanvas.clear();
                videoScreenCanvas.getCircleVideoShape().setCenterX(x);
                videoScreenCanvas.getCircleVideoShape().setCenterY(y);
                videoScreenCanvas.paintCircleVideoShape();
            }
        };
        
        videoScreenCanvas.addEventHandler(
                MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, 
                mouseEventHandler);
        
        stage.setResizable(false);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(videoScreenCanvas);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
        
        VideoRecordingThread videoRecordingThreadNoCompression = 
                new VideoRecordingThread(
                        videoScreenCanvas, 
                        VideoRecordingThread
                                .VideoCompressionAlgorithm
                                .NO_COMPRESSION);
        
        VideoRecordingThread videoRecordingThreadNaiveCompression = 
                new VideoRecordingThread(
                        videoScreenCanvas, 
                        VideoRecordingThread
                                .VideoCompressionAlgorithm
                                .NAIVE_COMPRESSOR);
        
        // Start recording.
        videoRecordingThreadNoCompression.start();
        videoRecordingThreadNaiveCompression.start();
        
        VideoCoordinatorThread videoCoordinatorThread = 
                new VideoCoordinatorThread(
                        videoScreenCanvas,
                        videoRecordingThreadNoCompression,
                        videoRecordingThreadNaiveCompression);
        
        videoCoordinatorThread.start();
    }
    
    private static void showBeginRecordingHint() {
        Alert beginInfoAlert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        beginInfoAlert.setTitle("Beginning recording");
        
        beginInfoAlert.setHeaderText(
                "Press OK and you will have 10 seconds to record the video.");
        
        beginInfoAlert.setContentText(
                "During the 10 seconds of recording, you can move " + 
                "the black circle by dragging it with the mouse.");
        
        beginInfoAlert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.compression.video.app.VideoCoordinatorThread.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.compression.video.app;

import com.github.coderodde.compression.util.Utils;
import com.github.coderodde.compression.util.VideoScreenCanvas;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;

/**
 * This thread is a fast drop-in for coordinating the playback threads.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jul 
 */
public final class VideoCoordinatorThread extends Thread {
    
    private static final long ITERATION_SLEEP_DURATION = 100L;
    
    private final VideoScreenCanvas videoScreenCanvas;
    private final VideoRecordingThread nonCompressiveVideoRecordingThread;
    private final VideoRecordingThread naiveCompressingVideoRecordingThread;
    
    public VideoCoordinatorThread(
            VideoScreenCanvas videoScreenCanvas,
            VideoRecordingThread nonCompressiveVideoRecordingThread,
            VideoRecordingThread naiveCompressingVideoRecordingThread) {
        
        this.videoScreenCanvas = videoScreenCanvas;
        
        this.nonCompressiveVideoRecordingThread = 
                nonCompressiveVideoRecordingThread;
        
        this.naiveCompressingVideoRecordingThread = 
                naiveCompressingVideoRecordingThread;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (nonCompressiveVideoRecordingThread.isRunning() ||
               naiveCompressingVideoRecordingThread.isRunning()) {
            Utils.sleep(ITERATION_SLEEP_DURATION);
        }
        
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Before playback");
            alert.setHeaderText(
                    "After pressing OK, a recording via non-compressive " + 
                    "recording starts.");
            
            alert.setContentText("Press OK, to view non-compressed video.");
            
            alert.showAndWait();
        });
        
        VideoPlaybackThread nonCompressiveVideoPlaybackThread = 
            new VideoPlaybackThread(
                videoScreenCanvas, 
                VideoRecordingThread.VideoCompressionAlgorithm.NO_COMPRESSION,
                nonCompressiveVideoRecordingThread.getBitArrayBuilder());
        
        nonCompressiveVideoPlaybackThread.start();
        
        try {
            nonCompressiveVideoPlaybackThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            
        }
        
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Before playback");
            alert.setHeaderText(
                    "After pressing OK, a recording via naively-compressed  " + 
                    "recording starts.");
            
            alert.setContentText(
                    "Press OK, to view the video with naive compressor.");
            
            // REVIEW REQUEST: How to make the showAndWait() block this thread?
            alert.showAndWait();
        });
        
        VideoPlaybackThread naiveCompressorVideoPlaybackThread = 
            new VideoPlaybackThread(
                videoScreenCanvas,  
                VideoRecordingThread.VideoCompressionAlgorithm.NO_COMPRESSION,
                nonCompressiveVideoRecordingThread.getBitArrayBuilder());
        
        naiveCompressorVideoPlaybackThread.start();
        
        try {
            naiveCompressorVideoPlaybackThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.compression.video.app.VideoPlaybackThread.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.compression.video.app;

import com.github.coderodde.compression.util.BitArrayBuilder;
import com.github.coderodde.compression.util.Utils;
import com.github.coderodde.compression.util.VideoScreenCanvas;
import static com.github.coderodde.compression.video.app.VideoRecordingThread.VideoCompressionAlgorithm.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

/**
 * This class implements the video playback thread.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jul 20, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Jul 20, 2023)
 */
public final class VideoPlaybackThread extends Thread {
    
    private final VideoScreenCanvas videoScreenCanvas;
    private final VideoRecordingThread.VideoCompressionAlgorithm algorithm;
    private final BitArrayBuilder bitArrayBuilder;
    private final Color[][] framePixels = 
            new Color[VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_HEIGHT]
                     [VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_WIDTH];
    
    public VideoPlaybackThread(
            VideoScreenCanvas videoScreenCanvas,
            VideoRecordingThread.VideoCompressionAlgorithm algorithm,
            BitArrayBuilder bitArrayBuilder) {
        
        this.videoScreenCanvas = videoScreenCanvas;
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
        this.bitArrayBuilder = bitArrayBuilder;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        switch (algorithm) {
            case NO_COMPRESSION:
                playbackWithNoCompression();
                return;
                
            case NAIVE_COMPRESSOR:
                playbackWithNaiveCompressor();
                return;
                
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Unknown playback algorithm: " + algorithm);
        }
    }
    
    private void playbackWithNoCompression() {
        long sleepDuration = 1000L / VideoCompressionApp.FRAMES_PER_SECOND;
        
        int frameBitsStartIndex = 0;
        int frameBitLength = VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_HEIGHT *
                             VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_WIDTH;
        
        for (int frameIndex = 0;
                frameIndex < VideoCompressionApp.FRAMES_PER_SECOND *
                             VideoCompressionApp.VIDEO_DURATION_SECONDS; 
                frameIndex++) {
            
            // Load framePixels with new pixels:
            loadFramePixels(frameBitsStartIndex);
            
            draw(framePixels);
            
            // Advance towards the next frame:
            frameBitsStartIndex += frameBitLength;
            Utils.sleep(sleepDuration);
        }
    }
    
    private void loadFramePixels(int frameBitStartIndex) {
        int bitIndex = frameBitStartIndex;
        
        for (int y = 0; y < framePixels.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < framePixels[0].length; x++, bitIndex++) {
                long bit = bitArrayBuilder.readBits(bitIndex, 1);
                
                if (bit == 1L) {
                    framePixels[y][x] = Color.BLACK;
                } else {
                    framePixels[y][x] = Color.WHITE;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void draw(Color[][] framePixels) {
        videoScreenCanvas.drawFrame(
                videoScreenCanvas.convertFramePixelsToImage(framePixels));
    }
    
    private void playbackWithNaiveCompressor() {
        long sleepDuration = 1000L / VideoCompressionApp.FRAMES_PER_SECOND;
        
        int frameBitLength = VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_HEIGHT *
                             VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_WIDTH;
        
        // Draw the initial frame:
        loadFramePixels(0);
        draw(framePixels);
        
        Color[][] previousPixels = framePixels;
        
        BitIndexHolder bitIndexHolder = new BitIndexHolder();
        bitIndexHolder.bitIndex = frameBitLength;
        
        for (int frameIndex = 1; 
                frameIndex < VideoCompressionApp.FRAMES_PER_SECOND * 
                             VideoCompressionApp.VIDEO_DURATION_SECONDS; 
                frameIndex++) {
            
            // Get the next frame::
            Color[][] nextPixels = 
                    loadNextPixels(
                            previousPixels, 
                            bitIndexHolder);
            
            draw(nextPixels);
            
            previousPixels = nextPixels;
            Utils.sleep(sleepDuration);
        }   
    }
    
    private Color[][] loadNextPixels(Color[][] previousPixels,
                                     BitIndexHolder bitIndexHolder) {
        // Compute the minimum number of bits sufficient to represent the
        // integer no larger than the number of pixels in a frame:
        int bitsInNumberOfPixels = 
                Utils.computeNumberOfBitsToStore(
                        VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_HEIGHT *
                        VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_WIDTH);
        
        // Compute the minimum number of bits sufficient to represent any valid
        // pixel X-coordinate:
        int bitsInXCoordinate = 
                Utils.computeNumberOfBitsToStore(
                        VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_WIDTH);
    
        // Compute the minimum number of bits sufficient to represent any valid
        // pixel Y-coordinate:
        int bitsInYCoordinate = 
                Utils.computeNumberOfBitsToStore(
                        VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        
        // Read the number of pixels that changed between the previous and
        // next frames:
        int numberOfChangedPixels = 
                (int) bitArrayBuilder.readBits(
                        bitIndexHolder.bitIndex,
                        bitsInNumberOfPixels);
        
        bitIndexHolder.bitIndex += bitsInNumberOfPixels;
        Color[][] nextPixels = 
                new Color[VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_HEIGHT]
                         [VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_WIDTH];
        
        for (int pixelIndex = 0; 
                pixelIndex < numberOfChangedPixels; 
                pixelIndex++) {
            // Read the X-coordinate of the pixel that changed between previous
            // and next frames:
            int x = 
                    (int) bitArrayBuilder.readBits(
                            bitIndexHolder.bitIndex, 
                            bitsInXCoordinate);
            
            // Advance towards the Y-coordinate:
            bitIndexHolder.bitIndex += bitsInXCoordinate;
            
            // Read the Y-coordinate of the pixel that changed between previous
            // and next frames:
            int y = 
                    (int) bitArrayBuilder.readBits(
                            bitIndexHolder.bitIndex,
                            bitsInYCoordinate);
            
            // Advance towards the next pixel:
            bitIndexHolder.bitIndex += bitsInYCoordinate;
            Color previousPixelColor = previousPixels[y][x];
            Color nextPixelColor = flipColor(previousPixelColor);
            nextPixels[y][x] = nextPixelColor;
        }
        
        return nextPixels;
    }
    
    private static Color flipColor(Color color) {
        return color == Color.WHITE ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE;
    }
    
    private static class BitIndexHolder {
        int bitIndex;
    } 
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.compression.video.app.VideoRecordingThread.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.compression.video.app;

import com.github.coderodde.compression.util.BitArrayBuilder;
import com.github.coderodde.compression.util.PixelColor;
import com.github.coderodde.compression.util.Utils;
import com.github.coderodde.compression.util.Utils.SleepDuration;
import com.github.coderodde.compression.util.VideoScreenCanvas;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import javafx.application.Platform;

public final class VideoRecordingThread extends Thread {
    
    public static enum VideoCompressionAlgorithm {
        NO_COMPRESSION,
        NAIVE_COMPRESSOR;
    }
    
    private final int framesToRecord;
    private final VideoScreenCanvas videoScreenCanvas;
    private final VideoCompressionAlgorithm compressionAlgorithm;
    private BitArrayBuilder bitArrayBuilder;
    private final AtomicBoolean isRunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    
    public VideoRecordingThread(
            VideoScreenCanvas videoScreenCanvas,
            VideoCompressionAlgorithm compressionAlgorithm) {
        
        this.videoScreenCanvas = videoScreenCanvas;
        
        this.framesToRecord = VideoCompressionApp.FRAMES_PER_SECOND *
                              VideoCompressionApp.VIDEO_DURATION_SECONDS;
        
        this.compressionAlgorithm = compressionAlgorithm;
    }
    
    public BitArrayBuilder getBitArrayBuilder() {
        return this.bitArrayBuilder;
    }
    
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning.get();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        switch (compressionAlgorithm) {
            case NO_COMPRESSION:
                recordWithNoCompression();
                isRunning.set(false);
                return;
                
            case NAIVE_COMPRESSOR:
                recordWithNaiveCompression();
                isRunning.set(false);
                return;
        }
        
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Unknown compression algorithm: " + compressionAlgorithm);
    }
    
    private void recordWithNoCompression() {
        SleepDuration sleepDuration = 
                Utils.getFrameSleepDuration(
                        VideoCompressionApp.FRAMES_PER_SECOND);

        int bitArrayBuilderCapacity = 
                VideoCompressionApp.FRAMES_PER_SECOND * 
                VideoCompressionApp.VIDEO_DURATION_SECONDS * 
                VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_WIDTH *
                VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_HEIGHT;

        bitArrayBuilder = new BitArrayBuilder(bitArrayBuilderCapacity);

        for (int frameIndex = 0; 
                frameIndex < framesToRecord; 
                frameIndex++) {

            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                videoScreenCanvas.clear();
                videoScreenCanvas.paintCircleVideoShape();
            });
            
            Utils.sleep(sleepDuration);

            PixelColor[][] pixelMatrix = 
                    videoScreenCanvas
                            .getCircleVideoShape()
                            .getColorMatrix();

            for (PixelColor[] pixelMatrixRow : pixelMatrix) {
                for (PixelColor pixelColor : pixelMatrixRow) {
                    bitArrayBuilder.appendBits(
                            pixelColor == PixelColor.WHITE ? 0L : 1L,
                            1);
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(
                "Bits in no compression bit array: " + bitArrayBuilder.size());
    }
    
    private void recordWithNaiveCompression() {
        SleepDuration sleepDuration = 
                Utils.getFrameSleepDuration(
                        VideoCompressionApp.FRAMES_PER_SECOND);
        
        bitArrayBuilder = new BitArrayBuilder();
        
        // Process the first frame:
        PixelColor[][] previousPixelMatrix = processFirstFrame();
        
        Utils.sleep(sleepDuration);
        
        for (int frameIndex = 1; frameIndex < framesToRecord; frameIndex++) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                videoScreenCanvas.clear();
                videoScreenCanvas.paintCircleVideoShape();
            });
            
            Utils.sleep(sleepDuration);
            
            PixelColor[][] currentPixelMatrix = 
                    videoScreenCanvas.getCircleVideoShape().getColorMatrix();
            
            loadBits(previousPixelMatrix, currentPixelMatrix);
            
            previousPixelMatrix = currentPixelMatrix;
        }
        
        System.out.println(
                "Bits in naive compressor bit array: " +
                        bitArrayBuilder.size());
    }
    
    private void loadBits(PixelColor[][] previousPixelMatrix, 
                          PixelColor[][] currentPixelMatrix) {
        int matrixHeight = previousPixelMatrix.length;
        int matrixWidth = previousPixelMatrix[0].length;
        
        int matrixYBitLength =
                Utils.computeNumberOfBitsToStore(matrixHeight);
        
        int matrixXBitLength =
                Utils.computeNumberOfBitsToStore(matrixWidth);
        
        Set<Point> changedPixelPoints = new HashSet<>();
        
        for (int y = 0; y < previousPixelMatrix.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < previousPixelMatrix[0].length; x++) {
                PixelColor previousPixelColor = previousPixelMatrix[y][x];
                PixelColor currentPixelColor = currentPixelMatrix[y][x];
                
                if (previousPixelColor != currentPixelColor) {
                    changedPixelPoints.add(new Point(x, y));
                }
            }
        }
        
        int changedPixelPointsBitLength = 
                Utils.computeNumberOfBitsToStore(
                        VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_WIDTH * 
                        VideoScreenCanvas.VIDEO_SCREEN_CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        
        bitArrayBuilder.appendBits(changedPixelPoints.size(),
                                   changedPixelPointsBitLength);
        
        for (Point point : changedPixelPoints) {
            bitArrayBuilder.appendBits(point.x, matrixXBitLength);
            bitArrayBuilder.appendBits(point.y, matrixYBitLength);
        }
    }
    
    private PixelColor[][] processFirstFrame() {
        PixelColor[][] pixelMatrix =
                videoScreenCanvas.getCircleVideoShape().getColorMatrix();
        
        for (int y = 0; y < pixelMatrix.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < pixelMatrix[0].length; x++) {
                if (pixelMatrix[y][x].equals(PixelColor.WHITE)) {
                    bitArrayBuilder.appendBits(0L, 1);
                } else {
                    bitArrayBuilder.appendBits(1L, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return pixelMatrix;
    }
}
```

**Typical output**

After the recording is done, both the recording threads output the number of bits it took to store the entire video. Looks like this:

```
Bits in no compression bit array: 240000000
Bits in naive compressor bit array: 27451650
```

**GitHub**

The entire repository is [here](https://github.com/coderodde/VideoCompressionApp).

Comment: "_How can I rewrite this...?_" is not a _review_ question, so don't expect answers to that.  It looks like you haven't finished writing this code to your satisfaction, and review should take place after you've done that.

Comment: @TobySpeight The only missing part is basically this: when the recording is over, a message box is presented. Next, the 1st playback must start *only* when the message box button is pressed. Even more, when the 1st playback is over, a second message box appears and the 2nd playback starts only after the OK-button of the second message box is pressed.

Comment: @TobySpeight Should I add that to the actual question?

Comment: Is the code working as you want it to?  If not, you should temporarily close the question and make the necessary changes.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, yet it would be nice to polish it a bit.

Comment: The `getDataByte()` `switch` seems tedious and could be a brief expression. If it is known to bench quicker than alternatives, please document that in a comment. I did not say "tedious and repetitive" because the zero case is different and merely casts to `byte`. Surely the seven masks are redundant? Or is there some sign-bit detail to worry about? Also, better to switch on the expression `byteIndex % Long.BYTES` rather than temporarily alter the meaning of what a "byte index" is. Similarly in `readBit()`, which BTW seems to loop more than necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some improvements:

**VideoCompressionApp class:**

This piece of code can be replace with something more elegant:

> ```
> EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
>             @Override
>             public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
>                 int x = (int) mouseEvent.getX();
>                 int y = (int) mouseEvent.getY();
>                 videoScreenCanvas.clear();
>                 videoScreenCanvas.getCircleVideoShape().setCenterX(x);
>                 videoScreenCanvas.getCircleVideoShape().setCenterY(y);
>                 videoScreenCanvas.paintCircleVideoShape();
>             }
>         };
> ```

You can replace with lambda:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseEventHandler = mouseEvent -> {
            int x = (int) mouseEvent.getX();
            int y = (int) mouseEvent.getY();
            videoScreenCanvas.clear();
            videoScreenCanvas.getCircleVideoShape().setCenterX(x);
            videoScreenCanvas.getCircleVideoShape().setCenterY(y);
            videoScreenCanvas.paintCircleVideoShape();
        };
```

Instead of duplicate code here:

> ```
> VideoRecordingThread videoRecordingThreadNoCompression = 
>                 new VideoRecordingThread(
>                         videoScreenCanvas, 
>                         VideoRecordingThread
>                                 .VideoCompressionAlgorithm
>                                 .NO_COMPRESSION);
>         
>         VideoRecordingThread videoRecordingThreadNaiveCompression = 
>                 new VideoRecordingThread(
>                         videoScreenCanvas, 
>                         VideoRecordingThread
>                                 .VideoCompressionAlgorithm
>                                 .NAIVE_COMPRESSOR);
> ```

You can extract a method:

```
private VideoRecordingThread createVideoRecordingThread(VideoCompressionAlgorithm compressionAlogrithm)
```

---

For **VideoRecordingThread class**:

> ```
> public static enum VideoCompressionAlgorithm {
>         NO_COMPRESSION,
>         NAIVE_COMPRESSOR;
>     }
> ```

`static` is redundant here; nested enum types are implicitly static.

Since you are working with JDK20 (just saw it in your `pom.xml`),
you can convert `switch`/`case` to the more elegant `switch`/`case` provided by JDK17.

So instead of:

> ```
> @Override
>     public void run() {
>         switch (compressionAlgorithm) {
>             case NO_COMPRESSION:
>                 recordWithNoCompression();
>                 isRunning.set(false);
>                 return;
>                 
>             case NAIVE_COMPRESSOR:
>                 recordWithNaiveCompression();
>                 isRunning.set(false);
>                 return;
>         }
>         
>         throw new IllegalStateException(
>                 "Unknown compression algorithm: " + compressionAlgorithm);
> }
> ```

better to enhance it with:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        switch (compressionAlgorithm) {
            case NO_COMPRESSION -> {
                recordWithNoCompression();
                isRunning.set(false);
                return;
            }
            case NAIVE_COMPRESSOR -> {
                recordWithNaiveCompression();
                isRunning.set(false);
                return;
            }
        }
        
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Unknown compression algorithm: " + compressionAlgorithm);
}
```

in the term of pretty switch case in JDK20.

---

Look at **BitArrayBuilder class**

Instead of your `getDataByte()`, I wrote my own as:

```
private byte getDataByte(int byteIndex) {
        long longData = bitArray[byteIndex / Long.BYTES];
        byteIndex %= Long.BYTES;

        return switch (byteIndex) {
            case 0 -> (byte) (longData);
            case 1 -> (byte) ((longData >> 8) & 0xFF);
            case 2 -> (byte) ((longData >> 16) & 0xFF);
            case 3 -> (byte) ((longData >> 24) & 0xFF);
            case 4 -> (byte) ((longData >> 32) & 0xFF);
            case 5 -> (byte) ((longData >> 40) & 0xFF);
            case 6 -> (byte) ((longData >> 48) & 0xFF);
            case 7 -> (byte) ((longData >> 56) & 0xFF);
            default -> throw new IllegalStateException("Should not get here ever.");
        };
    }
```

---

**Utils class**:

Since this class is static, you must declare a private constructor to force any instantiation of this class to be a compilation error.

You have duplicate code here:

> ```
> public static void sleep(long milliseconds, int nanoseconds) {
>         try {
>             Thread.sleep(milliseconds, nanoseconds);
>         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
>             
>         }
>     }
>     
>     public static void sleep(SleepDuration sleepDuration) {
>         try {
>             Thread.sleep(sleepDuration.millisecondsPart, 
>                          sleepDuration.nanosecondsPart);
>         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
>             
>         }
>     }
> ```

This could be:

```
public static void sleep(long milliseconds, int nanoseconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milliseconds, nanoseconds);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            
        }
    }
    
    public static void sleep(SleepDuration sleepDuration) {
        sleep(sleepDuration.millisecondsPart, sleepDuration.nanosecondsPart);
  }
```

You are catching errors with no handling in the `catch` part; this is not best practice. At least print something.

---

**PixelColor class**:

You have redundant semicolon after `Black` type.